# Twilio Error - ConnectionError (31005): Error sent from gateway in HANGUP

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twilio, twilio-api

Trying to connect two users to the same conference call, but getting this error first:

```
error:  ConnectionError: ConnectionError (53000): Raised whenever a signaling connection error occurs that is not covered by a more specific error code.
```

and then getting this error:

```
Received an error from the gateway: ConnectionError: ConnectionError (31005): Error sent from gateway in HANGUP
    at ConnectionError.TwilioError [as constructor]
```

In my TwiML error logs this is what I see:

```
TwiML response body too large
```

For full context, users are first matched together, this happens in the 'waiting room' component:

```
function createTwilioConference(username, matchedUser){
    const pairedUsers ={}
    pairedUsers['roomName'] = sortUsersAlphabetically([username,matchedUser]).join('')
    pairedUsers['participantLabel'] = sortUsersAlphabetically([username,matchedUser])
    pairedUsers['currUser'] = username
    pairedUsers['matchedUser'] = matchedUser
    axios.post(`${profileURL}voice_chat/rooms`,pairedUsers)
        .then(res =>{
            console.log('twilio call created', res.data)
        })
}
```

This function is wrapped in a useEffect that has an empty dependency array. Both users who have been matched together receive an XML object creating a twilio conference call

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Response><Dial><Conference participantLabel="['emmanuelS21', 'testingUser']" startConferenceOnEnter="true">emmanuelS21testingUser</Conference></Dial></Response>
```

The conference room name is the same for both users (sort their names alphabetically and concatenating them to create the room name).

Both users are then redirected to the pair programming session where the call is initiated:

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('!!!*** how many times is twilio being called ***!!!')
    const params = {
        roomName: roomName, participantLabel: user.username
    };
    if (!call) {
        const callPromise = device.connect({ params });
        callPromise.then((call) => {
        console.log(' ***what is call', call)
        setCall(call);
        });
    }
    if (!participants.current.includes(user.username)) {
            participants.current.push(user.username);
    }
}, []);
```

I'm not sure how big an issue this is, but I noticed that my useEffect is being called four times